# ¿Cómo mandar datos de base de datos MySql con PHP a Vue.Js?

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js

Tengo una falla conceptual muy grande.

1. Creo mi base de datos.
2. Obtengo los datos con Php y los puedo crear en un objeto Json.
3. **** Aquí no sé qué hacer, pero quiero que de PHP mandar el objeto al objeto Vue en su información data ****
4. Muestro la información en vue en un código estilo.

```html
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: NECESITAS obtenerlos por medio de ajax, usa axios o fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas entender que PHP se ejecuta de lado servidor, es decir antes de que se envíe al navegador, por el contrario JavaScript se ejecuta de lado cliente, es decir en el navegador. Puedes por lo tanto generar código js desde php facilmente.

El problema que planteas puedes resolverlo de 2 formas, incrustando código php sobre el js de la página generada con php o haciendo una nueva petición al servidor mediante ajax para que te traiga los datos que necesitas.

Un ejemplo incrustando php:

```
<?php

$variable_php = 'Esta cadena fue declarada en PHP';

?>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: '<?= $variable_php; ?>'
  }
})
</script>
```

Si la instancia vue esta en un archivo aparte, puedes declarar una variable global en js y luego asignarla en la instancia de vuejs, esta variable debe ser declarada antes de incuir el archivo que contendra la instalncia de vue, ejemplo:

```
<?php

$variable_php = 'Esta cadena fue declarada en PHP';

?>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
<script>
    var mimensaje = '<?= $variable_php; ?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./instancia_vue.js"></script>

// archivo instancia_vue.js
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: mimensaje
  }
})
</script>
```

La segunda opción sería utilizando ajax, te puedes apoyar en [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) o jquery para facilitar las cosas, ejemplo con axios:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
       // hacemos una petición get a la url que contiene los datos
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      // cuando tengamos la respuesta la asignamos a message
      .then(response => (this.message = response.data.chartName))
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es una respuesta muy clara.

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, tienes que usar una librería que haga peticiones a un servidor, puedes utilizar ajax de jquery o axios.

Revisa bien la documentación de [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/), cuando el componente de vue esta montado, ahí debes hacer la petición al servidor, en la respuesta, asignas esa respuesta a tu variable message.

Comment: ESTO NO Da respuesta a la pregunta pues más bien parece una opinión